# What is positive state of 'anymore' or 'no longer'?

Tags: meaning

I am usually facing situations which I need to use word 'anymore' or 'no longer' when writing. But, I want to use this word's meaning in positive sentences. However, they are being used in negative sentences as far as I know. So is there any equivalent word of 'anymore' or 'no longer' for positive sentences?

Thanks in advance.

Note: I think there is a word which is close to the word 'anymore' and 'no longer' in terms of meaning: "hereafter". Am I right? If I am right, please notify me.

Comment: Example? "I'm no longer depressed" or "I'm not depressed anymore" both sound quite positive.

Answer (score 3):

***Negative*** 'no longer,' 'anymore.'

> I no longer practice karate.
>   I don't read French anymore.

***Positive***  'still'

> I am still working on my thesis.
>   I still go to football.

***Qualified positive*** 'from time to time'

> I play the flute from time to time.